# Rotating a video on Chromecast

Tags: html, css, webkit, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to play a video on the `chromecast` in portrait mode (1080*1920), so rotated to 90°.

Using the [CastVideos](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome) example I'm trying to get it to display properly, but I keep getting a weird behaviour: **the video shows for an instant in its original rotation and then turns correctly**, as if the CSS is applied after the first frame of the video is drawn. How can I make my video directly appear with its scale and rotation done?

Here is the simple receiver I build which displays (or is supposed to display) the rotated video:

```
    <html>
<head>
  <title>Example minimum receiver</title>
  <script src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

<!--
Copyright (C) 2014 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    div{
        height:720PX;
        width:1280PX;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        background-color:#000000;
    }

    video
    {
        margin-top:720px;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.666) rotate(-90deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;

    }
    </style>
    <title>Cast Hello Text</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js"></script>
    <video id='media'/>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      window.mediaElement = document.getElementById('media');
      window.mediaManager = new cast.receiver.MediaManager(window.mediaElement);
      window.castReceiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();
      window.castReceiverManager.start();
        // handler for the 'ready' event
    castReceiverManager.onReady = function(event) {
          console.log('Received Ready event: ' + JSON.stringify(event.data));
          window.castReceiverManager.setApplicationState("Application status is ready...");
        };


    // handler for 'senderconnected' event
    castReceiverManager.onSenderConnected = function(event) {
      console.log('Received Sender Connected event: ' + event.data);
      console.log(window.castReceiverManager.getSender(event.data).userAgent);
    };

    // handler for 'senderdisconnected' event
    castReceiverManager.onSenderDisconnected = function(event) {
      console.log('Received Sender Disconnected event: ' + event.data);
      if (window.castReceiverManager.getSenders().length == 0) {
        window.close();
      }
    };

    // handler for 'systemvolumechanged' event
    castReceiverManager.onSystemVolumeChanged = function(event) {
      console.log('Received System Volume Changed event: ' + event.data['level'] + ' ' +
          event.data['muted']);
    };

    // create a CastMessageBus to handle messages for a custom namespace
    window.messageBus = window.castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus('*******my_cast_namespace*******');

    // handler for the CastMessageBus message event
    window.messageBus.onMessage = function(event) {
      console.log('Message [' + event.senderId + ']: ' + event.data);
      // display the message from the sender
      showVideo(event.data);
      // inform all senders on the CastMessageBus of the incoming message event
      // sender message listener will be invoked
      //window.messageBus.send(event.senderId, event.data);
    }

    // initialize the CastReceiverManager with an application status message
    window.castReceiverManager.start({statusText: "Application is starting"});
    console.log('Receiver Manager started');

  function showVideo(video) {
    console.log(video.src);
    document.getElementById("media").src=video;
    window.castReceiverManager.setApplicationState("Application is playing");
  };
  };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The important part here being the code to rotate the video:

```
video
{
   margin-top:720px;
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.666) rotate(-90deg);
   -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;       
}
```

Which only seems to be applied after the video's first frame is loaded to the screen => The video therefore flashes in its original position before being rotated and playing.

I have not experienced this behavior on Chrome, is there something I'm doing wrong in the Chromecast's build of Chrome ?